# A level Central Limit Theorem question

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

How many times must a fair die be rolled in order for there to be less than 1% chance that the mean of the scores differ from 3.5 by more than 0.1?

The answer is $n≥1936$, but how do you get to this answer?

Comment: Did you try to determine the formula for the confidence interval?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If $X$ is the number of faces showing on one roll, then $E(X) = 3.5$ and you need to find $V(X)$, and from it $V(\bar X)$. Also, assume $\bar X$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

**Find mean and variance for one fair die.** Let $X$ be the number of faces showing on one fair die.
$$\mu = E(X) = (1 + 2 + \cdots + 6)/6 = [6(7)/2]/6 = 7/2 = 3.5,$$
where we have used the formula that the sum of the first $n$ integers
is $n(n+1)/2.$ Also,
$$E(X^2) = (1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 6^2)/6 = \frac{6(7)(13)/6}{6} = 91/6,$$
where we have used the formula that the sum of the first $n$ squares
is $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6.$ Then
$$ \sigma^2 = V(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2 = \frac{91}{6} - \frac{49}{4}
\frac{182 - 147}{12} = 35/12.$$
There are, of course, other methods of finding $\mu$ and $\sigma^2.$

**Find the mean and variance for the average of $n$ dice.** For the average $\bar X_n$ on $n$ rolls of a die, we have
$$\mu_n = E[(X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n)/n] = n\mu/n = \mu.$$ 
and, because we assume the $n$ rolls of the die are independent,
$$\sigma^2_n = V[(X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n)/n] = n\sigma^2/n^2 = \sigma^2/n.$$

**Assume the average is normally distributed.** If $n$ is even moderately large
the Central Limit Theorem indicates that $\bar X_n$ has approximately
the normal distribution with mean $\mu_n = 7/2$ and variance 
$\sigma_n^2 = \sigma^2/n = \frac{35}{12n}.$

Thus, upon standardizing (here, dividing by $\sigma_n$), we have
 $$P\{-0.1 < \bar X_n - 7/2 < 0.1\} \approx 
P\{-0.1\sqrt{12n/35} < Z < 0.1\sqrt{12n/35} \},$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.
Because we want this probability to equal $.01 = 1\%,$ we note that
$P\{-2.576 < Z < 2.576\} = 0.1.$

So in order to find the desired $n,$ we set $2.576 = 0.1\sqrt{12n/35},$
solve for $n$ and round up to the nearest integer. This gives the claimed answer $n = 1936$.

Comment: Some of this may already be in your textbook, and you may have to fill in some gaps. If anything is unclear, leave a comment.

Comment: The law of large numbers indicates nothing about the distribution of $\bar X_n$ except that $\bar X_n\to\mu$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did. Thanks. Wrote it before coffee. Changing it to CLT.

Comment: @Did Doesn't it say that it approaches a degenerate distribution?

Comment: @JohnK: If 'it' refers to the LLN of my pre-coffee blunder, then Yes. If 'it' refers to the CLT of the edited version, then No. Very roughly speaking, the LLN has $n$ in the denominator and the CLT has $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator. Two fundamentally different limits result.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the general result of the LLN. It does have distributional implications.

Comment: @JohnK "the LLN... does have distributional implications" Indeed the convergence in distribution of $\bar X_n$ to $\mu$ follows from the LLN but (i) this convergence in distribution is strictly weaker than the almost sure convergence asserted by the LLN, and (ii) this is not the convergence in distribution asserted by the CLT.